# Java constructor is not working

Tags: java, string, vector, constructor

I built my own class for handling a vector, unfortunately the constructor is not working right.

This is my vectorHandler.java:

```
public class vectorHandler {
    String text, completeText;
    int id;

    public vectorHandler(int id, String text, String completeText) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.completeText = completeText;
    }

    public void getData() {
        System.out.printf("** Datenausgabe ID %d **\n\nIn diesem Durchlauf eingegebener Wert: %s\nWert zu disem Zeitpunkt gesamt: %s\n\n", id, text, completeText);
    }   
}
```

I want to handle data from a loop with this class and put it into a vector as Objects.

In my Strings.java file, I want to use this class like this:

```
vectorHandler p = new vectorHandler(s, "TestX", i);
```

Error: The constructor vectorHandler (StringBuffer, String, int) is undefined.

Comment: You are passing an integer on the 3rd argument which actually expects a String

Comment: Your 3rd parameter of the constructor is a string and you're trying to pass it an integer. Look at the error message, it's your best friend. On top of that you're also passing it a `StringBuffer` instead of an int. Sidenote: paste all code here, do not link to external sites.

Comment: The error is very descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor  declared as:

```
public vectorHandler(int id, String text, String completeText)
```

And you try to call it with:

```
vectorHandler (StringBuffer, String, int)
```

You need to call it with the proper arguments in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

You are passed parameters like

```
vectorHandler p = new vectorHandler(s, "TestX", i);
```

in this i thought that

`s` is `StringBuffer`,

`textx` is `String`,

`i` is `int`

So parse it as

```
vectorHandler p = new vectorHandler(i, "TestX", s);
                                    ^     ^     ^
                                   int String  String
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ i agree :)

Answer (score 1):

`i` is an `int`, whereas your constructor takes a `String` in the 3rd position. Also, your constructor is expecting an `int` in the first position and you are passing a `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

as per the constructor it accepts arguements of `int`,`String` ,`string` but you are passing `string`,`string` ,`int`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a case of your program "not working properly", but more a case of it not having been constructed properly; you are attempting to call your constructor with the incorrect type of arguments which is causing the error.

To clarify, `i` is an `int` variable whereas your constructor requires a `String` variable.